# How to solve "Undefined symbol init_xrpow_core_sse" when linking lame mp3 encoder into iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, lame, i386

Based on [How can I compile lame as static library...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207063/how-can-i-compile-lame-as-static-library-a-for-armv6-and-armv7-of-iphone/10876381#10876381), I've compiled lame using this script on a macbook pro:

```
mkdir -p build
rm -rf build/* #*/


function build_lame()
{
    make distclean

    ./configure \
        CFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/${SDK}.platform/Developer/SDKs/$SDK$SDK_VERSION.sdk" \
        CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch $PLATFORM -miphoneos-version-min=7.0" \
        --prefix="/Users/$USER/Desktop/$PROJECTNAME" \
        --host="arm-apple-darwin9" \
        --disable-shared \
        --enable-static \
        --disable-frontend \

    make
    cp "$PROJECTNAME/.libs/$PROJECTNAME.a" "build/$PROJECTNAME-$PLATFORM.a"
}


PROJECTNAME=libmp3lame
SDK_VERSION=7.0


SDK="iPhoneSimulator"
PLATFORM="i386"
build_lame

SDK="iPhoneOS"
PLATFORM="armv7"
build_lame

SDK="iPhoneOS"
PLATFORM="armv7s"
build_lame


lipo -create build/$PROJECTNAME-* -output build/$PROJECTNAME.a
```

I then added the resulting `libmp3lame.a` to an iPhone project in Xcode 5.0.2. When building for an iOS device, it works fine. My problem starts when building for the simulator. When doing this, I get the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_init_xrpow_core_sse", referenced from:
      _init_xrpow_core_init in libmp3lame.a(quantize.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why does this error occur and how to solve it?

Here is a code snippet from `quantize.c` from the lame library:

```
static void
init_xrpow_core_c(gr_info * const cod_info, FLOAT xrpow[576], int upper, FLOAT * sum)
{
    // here, the initialization of xrpow is done in normal c code (i've cut that out to keep it small)
}

void
init_xrpow_core_init(lame_internal_flags * const gfc)
{
    gfc->init_xrpow_core = init_xrpow_core_c;

#if defined(HAVE_XMMINTRIN_H)
    if (gfc->CPU_features.SSE)
        gfc->init_xrpow_core = init_xrpow_core_sse;
#endif
#ifndef HAVE_NASM
#ifdef MIN_ARCH_SSE
    gfc->init_xrpow_core = init_xrpow_core_sse;
#endif
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `--host` parameter to `configure`. It needs to be changed depending on the machine on which you want to run the Simulator. In my case, this is a MacBook Pro from mid 2009, running Mac OS X 10.8.5.

`uname -a` reports:

```
Darwin <my computer name>.local 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

So I wildly guessed that the `--host` parameter for `configure` for this environment, in which the Simulator runs, needs to be set to `i686-apple-darwin12.5.0`. The guess was right. My build script now looks like this:

```
mkdir -p build
rm -rf build/* #*/


function build_lame()
{
    make distclean

    ./configure \
        CFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/${SDK}.platform/Developer/SDKs/$SDK$SDK_VERSION.sdk" \
        CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch $PLATFORM -miphoneos-version-min=7.0" \
        --prefix="/Users/$USER/Desktop/$PROJECTNAME" \
        --host="$HOST" \
        --disable-shared \
        --enable-static \
        --disable-frontend \

    make
    cp "$PROJECTNAME/.libs/$PROJECTNAME.a" "build/$PROJECTNAME-$PLATFORM.a"
}


PROJECTNAME=libmp3lame
SDK_VERSION=7.0


SDK="iPhoneSimulator"
HOST="i686-apple-darwin12.5.0"
PLATFORM="i686"
build_lame

SDK="iPhoneOS"
HOST="arm-apple-darwin9"
PLATFORM="armv7"
build_lame

SDK="iPhoneOS"
HOST="arm-apple-darwin9"
PLATFORM="armv7s"
build_lame


lipo -create build/$PROJECTNAME-* -output build/$PROJECTNAME.a
```

This works when building for Simulator in Xcode.