# Lipo in not creating for arm64, armv7

Tags: ios, iphone, mp3, static-libraries, lame

I'm using the LAME MP3 encoder to convert the caf formatted file to MP3 format. I downloaded LAME and compile and build all architecture like arm64, armv7, armv7s, armv6, i386, i686, x86_64 successfully. I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207063/how-can-i-compile-lame-as-static-library-a-for-armv6-and-armv7-of-iphone) to create the libraries.

But I'm trying to create lipo for armv7, arm64, x86_64 which support to my project. But I'm getting fatal error.

Here is the error that I'm getting.

> fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: build/libmp3lame-arm64.a and build/libmp3lame-armv7.a have the same architectures (x86_64) and can't be in the same fat output file.

I tried the all combination which two architectures can create fat file, except single only creating. I need it for ios 8.1 and above (please mention which architectures should I put in the fat file for iPhone 4s and above)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something went wrong with your build: `libmp3lame-arm64.a`, `libmp3lame-armv7.a` should have been device builds but they seem to have come out as simulator builds.

You can confirm this by running `file` on them:

```
file build/libmp3lame-arm64.a build/libmp3lame-armv7.a
```

I don't know why it happened, nor which of many answers you used in the  question you linked to.

Can you give more information on how you configured and built lame?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply i already checked indivisual libmp3lame-i386.a with my project its working good. I think i386 is only for simulator!! i'm trying to combine all the library file into one FAT file